# Property returns string from base class while member returns string from inherited class?

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, variable-assignment

Here is the program:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyInheritedClass InheritInstance = new MyInheritedClass();
        Console.WriteLine(InheritInstance.name); // the name field
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string name= "I am the Base"; // the name field
    public string Name   // the Name property
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}

public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
{
    new public string name= "I inherit Base";
}
```

This works as expected. the output is: "I inherit Base"

Now if I change `Console.WriteLine(InheritInstance.name); // the name field` to `Console.WriteLine(InheritInstance.Name); // the name property`, it magically outputs: "I am Base"

I am baffled as to WHY this happens? I called the `Name` property of `MyInheritedClass`, how did the `Name` property of `MyClass` get called? Or maybe the `Name` property of `MyClass` is called and it somehow magically accesses the name field of `MyClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls your base class property because the `Name` property is defined only in the base class. This is the default and simplest behavior of inheritance. You can access properties from the base class.

When you need control over a property from the Base class you can use the `override` or `new` constructs to define your desired behavior for the property in the Child class.

Comment: Aha! So a child class can only access members of the parent class. It doesn't get copies of those members.

Comment: @discussedterran No, it does not get copies of the properties. Not at all

Comment: does it get copies of the fields or methods?

Answer (score 2):

> Now if I change Console.WriteLine(InheritInstance.name); // the name
>   field to Console.WriteLine(InheritInstance.Name); // the name
>   property, it magically outputs: "I am Base"

This happens because `MyClass` is unaware of the `new` operator in your derived class. As far as it knows, it only has one string field called `Name`, which is declared in the base class. When the property has the retrieve it via the getter, it goes to the `name` declared there.

As the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) say:

> When used as a declaration modifier, the new keyword **explicitly hides
>   a member that is inherited from a base class.** When you hide an
>   inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the base
>   class version

If you want to override that behavior, you can declare `name` as `virtual`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string name = "I am the Base";
    public virtual string Name { get { return this.name; } }
}

public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
{
    public new string name = "I inherit Base";
    public override string Name { get { return this.name } };
}
```

Note this looks and feels redundant. You can avoid that by declaring a single `virtual` property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "I am base" } }
}

public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
{
    public override string Name { get { return "I am derived" } };
}
```